# Filter "base query" for slightly different results

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to query a database using Entity Framework and I need to make several slightly different queries on the same set of tables. There are a load of navigation properties I need to add and it seems logical to me that I should be able to define the "base query" (i.e the one with all the navigation properties" and then further filter this as required and execute the query.

Some code may help explain further. This is what I am calling my "base query"

```
private static IEnumerable<HelpdeskTicket> GetAll()
{
    IEnumerable<HelpdeskTicket> Tickets;

    using (ItManagement_Entities db = new ItManagement_Entities())
    {
        Tickets = db.HelpdeskTickets.Include("CreatedByPerson")
                                    .Include("HelpdeskCategory")
                                    .Include("HelpdeskPriority")
                                    .Include("HelpdeskStatus");
    }

    return Tickets;
}
```

As an example, some of the queries I need to perform are open tickets, recently closed tickets, my tickets, yada yada yada.

My thinking is to have methods similar to the following to do the filtering bit I need without having to define all the `.Include()`'s again.

```
public static List<HelpdeskTicketModel> GetAllTickets()
{
    List<HelpdeskTicketModel> Tickets = new List<HelpdeskTicketModel>();

    GetAll().OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketId)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(t => Tickets.Add(HelpdeskTicketModel.Map(t)));

    return Tickets;
}

public static List<HelpdeskTicketModel> GetRecentlyClosedTickets()
{
    List<HelpdeskTicketModel> Tickets = new List<HelpdeskTicketModel>();

    GetAll().Where(t => t.HelpdeskStatus.IsClosedStatus)
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.ClosedTime)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(t => Tickets.Add(HelpdeskTicketModel.Map(t)));

    return Tickets;
}

//And so on...
```

When I try this I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception thrown complaining that `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed`, which makes sense really because my query *was* in a different context, in the `GetAll` method.

Question is, how do I go about doing what I want?

Comment: You could always pass your dbcontext into your GetAllTickets method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something similar to the [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method), where each particular method calls some base, private methods that do the common work and then each one adds its particular bits of the query. Something like that may come handy as a starting point:

```
// Here you define common parts applicable to all methods, or at least shared among some of them
private static IQueryable<HelpdeskTicket> BuildBaseQuery(this IQueryable<HelpdeskTicket> query)
{
    return query.Include("CreatedByPerson")
                .Include("HelpdeskCategory")
                .Include("HelpdeskPriority")
                .Include("HelpdeskStatus");
}

// Here are the particular methods, they create a query, call helper methods for the common bits and add their specifics
public static List<HelpdeskTicketModel> GetAllTickets()
{
    List<HelpdeskTicketModel> Tickets = new List<HelpdeskTicketModel>();

    using (ItManagement_Entities db = new ItManagement_Entities())
    {
        Tickets = db.HelpdeskTickets.BuildBaseQuery()
                                    .OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketId)
                                    .ToList()
                                    .ForEach(t => Tickets.Add(HelpdeskTicketModel.Map(t)));
    }

    return Tickets;
}
```